# Is there a php function to convert these characters?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I am using a lot of str_replace such as:

```
$prune = str_replace("&#39;", '\'', $prune);
$prune = str_replace('&#8217;', '\'', $prune);
$prune = str_replace('&#8211;', '-', $prune);
$prune = str_replace('&ldquo;', '', $prune);
$prune = str_replace('&quot;', '', $prune);
$prune = str_replace('&#233', 'e', $prune);
$prune = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $prune);
```

Is there a simpler PHP function for this, such as [htmlspecialchars_decode()](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode)?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for  [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php); it mirrors `htmlentities` as `htmlspecialchars_decode` mirrors `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work. It couldn't convert '&#8217;' to the single quote.

Comment: It does when I use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use arrays in str_replace

```
$search  = array("&#39;", '&#8217;', '&#8211;', '&ldquo;', '&quot;', '&#233', '&amp;');
$replace = array('\'', '\'', '-', '', '', 'e', '&');
$prune = str_replace($search, $replace, $prune);
```

Comment: thanks, I did do that in other application.  I was wondering whether there was a built-in PHP function.  I don't even know what these character are called :)

Comment: Why not use `strtr` and keep the search => replace pairs together? That way you don't have to count that `'&#233'` maps to the 6th item in `$replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Try $prune = htmlspecialchars_decode($prune);

Click https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php